# CSV diff with headers

Tags: python, csv

I am taking two csvs and writing the difference to a third csv file. Here's my function.

```
def diff_csv(NewFile, OldFile):
    with open(OldFile, 'r') as t1, open(NewFile, 'r') as t2:
        fileone = t1.readlines()
        filetwo = t2.readlines()

    with open('result.csv', 'w') as outFile:
        for line in filetwo:
            if line not in fileone:
                outFile.write(line)
```

However, since the two input csvs have the same set of hearders, the headers doesn't show up in the output csv. How do I preserve the headers here?

Comment: Do the diff process only from the second line of the files. Add the first line from any of the files to the third file before the loop .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter`. Then unconditionally write the header row, but for the other rows first test whether they exist in `old_file`. For this test, in the example below, I am making a set of rows from `old_file` to test inclusion, and representing the rows using a tuple of cell values because this is a hashable object that can be stored in a set.

```
import csv
import pdb

def diff_csv(new_file, old_file, out_file='result.csv'):

    with open(old_file) as t1, open(new_file) as t2:
        c2 = csv.DictReader(t2)
        c1 = csv.DictReader(t1)
        assert c2.fieldnames == c1.fieldnames
        row_tuples = set()
        for row in c1:
            row_tuples.add(tuple(row.values()))

        with open(out_file, "w") as fout:
            cout = csv.DictWriter(fout, c2.fieldnames)
            cout.writeheader()
            for row in c2:
                row_tuple = tuple(row.values())
                if row_tuple not in row_tuples:
                    cout.writerow(row)                

                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    diff_csv("b.csv", "a.csv")
```

with these input files:

`a.csv`

```
blah,stuff
a,4
b,6
```

and `b.csv`

```
blah,stuff
x,4
b,6
d,3
```

gives `result.csv`

```
blah,stuff
x,4
d,3
```